# C# - jQuery 1.8.0 extend method issue

Tags: c#, jquery, frontend, extension-methods

I have the following extension method for jQuery to serialize Json called `jquery.extension.js`:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    serializeJSON: function () {
        return this.serializeArray().reduce(function (result, item) {
            result[item.name] = item.value;
            return result;
        }, {});
    }
});
```

And I have these references on my layout:

```
<script src="~/Content/Script/jquery.extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On my view I call the method like this:

```
 function createList(e) {
        var form = $(this),
            dataJSON = serializeJSON(form),
            $saveBtn = $('#create-list-btn');
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: serializeJSON is not defined
```

Could anyone help me realize what is missing here?

Comment: Where are you even loading your extension method file?

Comment: Do you mean that I should include it on the BundleConfig?

Comment: Im loading it on the layout, I put it on the question.

Comment: Is this you loading your custom method file `<script src="~/Content/Script/jquery.extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` ?? If so, you probably need to load the `jQuery` file first, and then your custom method file, or else `jQuery` is going to be `undefined` inside your custom method.

Comment: Yes, I changed it and I'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem myself, the proper way to use it on the view is:

```
dataJSON = $(form).serializeJSON()
```

instead of:

```
dataJSON = serializeJSON(form)
```